# Lua split string considering nil entry

Tags: string, split, lua, strsplit

```
str = "cat,dog,,horse"
for word in string.gmatch(str, "([^,'',%s]+)") do
    print(word)
end
```

This code outputs the following.

```
cat
dog
horse
```

I want to consider nil entry as well and want to have the following output.

```
cat
dog
nil
horse
```

How can this be done? Could someone please point out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- `nil ~= ""`. You probably want the *empty string* rather than *nil* here. It is however trivial to convert one into the other, so I'll be using the empty string in the following code.
- You don't need the parentheses around the `gmatch` pattern. If there are no "captures" (parentheses), the entire pattern is implicitly captured.
- I'm rather confused about the intent of your pattern. You're matching sequences of one or more non-(whitespace, comma, or single quote) characters; that is, you're splitting on all of whitespace, commata, and single quotes. For some reason, you also have `'` and `,` twice in the character class; just once suffices. I'll be assuming you want to split by `,`.

The issue is that currently your pattern uses the `+` (one or more) quantifier when you want `*` (zero or more). Just using `*` works completely fine on Lua 5.4:

```lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local str = "cat,dog,,horse"; for word in str:gmatch"[^,]*" do print(word) end
cat
dog

horse
```

However, there is an issue when you try to run that same code on LuaJIT: It will produce seemingly random empty strings rather than only producing an empty string for two consecutive delimiters (this could be seen as "technically correct" since the empty string is a match for `*`, but I see it as a violation of the greediness of `*`). One solution is to require each match to end with a delimiter, appending a delimiter, and matching everything but the delimiter:

```lua
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall. http://luajit.org/
JIT: ON SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 AMD BMI2 fold cse dce fwd dse narrow loop abc sink fuse
> local str = "cat,dog,,horse"; for word in (str .. ","):gmatch("(.-),") do print(word) end
cat
dog

horse
```

A third option would be to split manually using repeated calls to `string.find`. Here's the utility I wrote myself for that:

```lua
function spliterator(str, delim, plain)
    assert(delim ~= "")
    local last_delim_end = 0

    -- Iterator of possibly empty substrings between two matches of the delimiter
    -- To exclude empty strings, filter the iterator or use `:gmatch"[...]+"` instead
    return function()
        if not last_delim_end then
            return
        end

        local delim_start, delim_end = str:find(delim, last_delim_end + 1, plain)
        local substr
        if delim_start then
            substr = str:sub(last_delim_end + 1, delim_start - 1)
        else
            substr = str:sub(last_delim_end + 1)
        end
        last_delim_end = delim_end
        return substr
    end
end
```

The usage in this example would be

```lua
for word in spliterator("cat,dog,,horse", ",") do print(word) end
```

Whether you want to add this to the `string` table, keep it in a local variable or perhaps a `require`d string util module is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this

```lua
  str = "cat,dog,,horse"
  for word in string.gmatch(str..',', "([^,]*),") do
    print(word == '' and 'nil' or word)
  end
```